# How do I know if it's safe to use a Nikon SB-20 on an Olympus E-520?

Tags: flash, compatibility, safety

I have an Olympus E-520 and I borrowed a Nikon SB-20 flash which I intend to use as an optical trigger for an off-camera flash (TTL connectors on the flash connector are removed to avoid mixing ttl signals). How do I find out if it's safe to use on my camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the there is a [flash trigger voltage overview site](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html) that says Nikon SB-20 has a trigger voltage of 5.5V, and that some older Olympus digicams has trigger voltage of 10V, and that Olympus recommends something in 3-6V range. There's a related thread [on dpreview forums](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1022&message=31934972&changemode=1) that suggests that flashes in this range should be okay.